# javascript searching array for array indices?

Tags: javascript

Say I have:

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Is this wrong?

```
a.indexOf([1,2])
```

Why -1?

Comment: That's something for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ThiefMaster should be moved to SO

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters.  Programming questions are off-topic here.  You should instead ask this on Stack Overflow (it will probably be moved there shortly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `[1,2] == [1,2]` is `false`

There is no equality of different instances of javascript objects.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) on `==` :

> If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal
>   references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in
>   memory.

You could build your own function to look for an array in an array, but in this case, as you would have to check all elements of the internal arrays (or build a hash code), this won't be fast. You'd better avoid this kind of search.

Comment: That's not always avoidable. That's why jQuery and most other JS libs provide a shallow comparison as well as a deep comparison function. It's rather useful when you need to determine if two objects are "equal" in terms of their scalar value properties. However, jQuery's object comparison is not necessarily ideal for arrays since objects don't have a specific property order, but numerically-indexed arrays do have an inherent item order.

Comment: It's still slow and heavy. I agree it's not always avoidable but part of the design task is to avoid this kind of bottlenecks in your application.

Comment: Right, that's why you try to avoid deep comparisons if you can. But I believe jQuery's deep comparison actually has pretty decent performance IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You **CANNOT** compare ARRAYS in JAVASCRIPT!

JavaScript Arrays are essentially inherited from objects when you check equality condition the internal references of these tow objects are different which returns -1 despite if all the elements are same

So when you call .indexOf it will compare arrays which will fail and hence you get -1

You need to build your own function which deeply checks if the Array and its sub arrays are equal or you can use some libraries like _.js